# org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: DATEDIF

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I used a formula in excel sheet: `=DATEDIF(TODAY(),E2,"y") & " years " & DATEDIF(TODAY(),E2,"ym") & " months " & DATEDIF(TODAY(),E2,"md") & " days" where E2 = 14-Aug-2015`

On Execution of `HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb)` I am getting and Exception of

> org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: DATEDIF

Please help.

Comment: Have you made sure you're using the most recent version of Apache POI?

Answer (score 4):

As of Apache POI version 3.12, DATEDIF() isn't supported.  You can check which functions are supported by running:

`Collection<String> supportedFuncs = WorkbookEvaluator.getSupportedFunctionNames();`

This [link](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html) describes how to write a user defined function and register it with the formula evaluator:

> ### [Two base interfaces to start your implementation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#Two+base+interfaces+to+start+your+implementation)
>
> All Excel formula function classes implement either org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Function or org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction interface. Function is a common interface for the functions defined in the binary Excel format (BIFF8): these are "classic" Excel functions like SUM, COUNT, LOOKUP, etc. FreeRefFunction is a common interface for the functions from the Excel Analysis Toolpack and for User-Defined Functions. In the future these two interfaces are expected be unified into one, but for now you have to start your implementation from two slightly different roots.
>
> ### [Which interface to start from?](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#Which+interface+to+start+from%3F)
>
> You are about to implement a function XXX and don't know which interface to start from: Function or FreeRefFunction. Use the following code to check whether your function is from the excel Analysis Toolpack:
>
> ```
> if(AnalysisToolPack.isATPFunction(functionName)){
>     // the function implements org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Function
> } else {
>     // the function implements org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction
> }
> ```
>
> ### [Walkthrough of an "evaluate()" implementation.](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#Walkthrough+of+an+%22evaluate%28%29%22+implementation.)
>
> Here is the fun part: lets walk through the implementation of the excel function **SQRT()**
>
> AnalysisToolPack.isATPFunction("SQRTPI") returns false so the base interface is Function. There are sub-interfaces that make life easier when implementing numeric functions or functions with fixed number of arguments, 1-arg, 2-arg and 3-arg function:
>
> - org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.NumericFunction
> - org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Fixed1ArgFunction
> - org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction
> - org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Fixed3ArgFunction
> - org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Fixed4ArgFunction
>
> Since SQRTPI takes exactly one argument we start our implementation from org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.Fixed1ArgFunction:
>
> ```
> Function SQRTPI = new Fixed1ArgFunction() {
>     public ValueEval evaluate(int srcRowIndex, int srcColumnIndex, ValueEval arg0) {
>         try {
>             // Retrieves a single value from a variety of different argument types according to standard
>             // Excel rules.  Does not perform any type conversion.
>             ValueEval ve = OperandResolver.getSingleValue(arg0, srcRowIndex, srcColumnIndex);
>
>             // Applies some conversion rules if the supplied value is not already a number.
>             // Throws EvaluationException(#VALUE!) if the supplied parameter is not a number
>             double arg = OperandResolver.coerceValueToDouble(ve);
>
>             // this where all the heavy-lifting happens
>             double result = Math.sqrt(arg*Math.PI);
>
>             // Excel uses the error code #NUM! instead of IEEE _NaN_ and _Infinity_,
>             // so when a numeric function evaluates to Double.NaN or Double.Infinity,
>             // be sure to translate the result to the appropriate error code
>             if (Double.isNaN(result) || Double.isInfinite(result)) {
>                 throw new EvaluationException(ErrorEval.NUM_ERROR);
>             }
>
>             return new NumberEval(result);
>         } catch (EvaluationException e){
>             return e.getErrorEval();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now when the implementation is ready we need to register it in the formula evaluator:
>
> ```
> WorkbookEvaluator.registerFunction("SQRTPI", SQRTPI);
> ```
>
> Voila! The formula evaluator now recognizes SQRTPI!
>
> -- https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html