# Exception while evaluating formula CELL using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, notimplementedexception

I am getting following exception when trying to evaluate all cell in workbook.
I am using version 3.13 for Apache poi. 
Formula is CELL("filename")

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedFunctionException: CELL
```

Is there any way to make it work? Or is there any other formula which will give me the same result?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129907/org-apache-poi-ss-formula-eval-notimplementedexception-datedif

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#appendixA), the function CELL is not supported/implemented in Apache POI.

I ran into a similar problem in a project a year or so ago. We ended up creating a user defined function in excel, which we then reimplemented in Java. Check this [link](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/user-defined-functions.html) for more information on user defined functions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the formula evaluator did not work. We decided to extract the numerical value from the function cell using cell.getNumericCellValue(), getting the result of evaluating the function:

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = new XSSFFormulaEvaluator(workbook);

formulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell(cell); // NotImplementedException (caused by NotImplementedFunctionException)
cell.getNumericCellValue();            // OK
```

Apache POI version 3.17