# How to execute excel formula using java Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, xls

I am trying to execute some formula using java apache poi API, however 
as a first step I can able to create a new sheet and fill required data. 
Now, as step two I want to execute formula on the populated data, formula is able to put in cell but result is not displaying when I open the excel sheet,

Please find inline image for better understanding, here G4 is displaying as **#NAME?** but what actual cell value is =G3*SQRT(5).

[image]

Expected: Using java, If we create a excel and execute formula then upon opening excel sheet should display the formula calculated result without any manual intervention

Actual: After opening the excel, cell data is showing as #NAME?  as if the formula is not recognized by excel, however, if I click respective cell to edit then the expected result is displaying

Code:

```
appendCellValue(sheet, 3, colIndex+3, true, "G3*SQRT(5)", null);
...
...
...
appendCellValue(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowIndex, int colIndex,boolean isFormula, String value, CellStyle cellStyle) {
    Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(colIndex);
    if(isFormula) {
        cell.setCellFormula(value);
    } else {
        cell.setCellValue(value);
    }
    if(cellStyle != null) {
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the code?

Comment: `workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();`

Comment: What formula is in `G3`? This formula results in `#Name?` error already. So it is not surprising that all what refers to `G3` also results in that error too.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: I am seeing this error now,

Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell ScoreBoard!G3

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31148486/7109162). Also which version of apache-poi do you use?

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBaumer looks like it's the poi version [4.1.0] problem. I have also figured it out there is another exception, while calculating stdev.p formula. stdev is working but not stdev.p :(. 
Anyway, Thank you again for helping out on actual issue :)